# How can I get the information from one field in a query to use in another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I am still trying to finish fixing my details page and I need one more piece to fix it.

I start with this query.

NOTE:recordID actually comes in from the previous page by clicking an item.
Also, name, img, item_code, and type_id are fields in my table not outside sources.

```
$recordID = $_GET['recordID'];
$query_master_details = "SELECT * FROM master_list WHERE master_list.master_id = $recordID";
$master_details = mysqli_query($conn, $query_master_details) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_master_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($master_details);
$totalrows_master_details = mysqli_num_rows($master_details);
```

Now, I have created this to determine how to display the details about said item:

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></h2></div>
  <?php
  $crafted = "SELECT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `type_id` <= 3 AND `length` = $row_master_details.length ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $crafted);
  $crafted = array();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $crafted[] = $row;
      }
  }
  if ($row_master_details['type_id'] > 3) {?>
    <p><strong>Code 1</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $crafted['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $crafted['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $crafted['item_code']; ?></p>
    <br><br>
    <p><strong>Code 2</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_master_details['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['item_code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['length']; ?> Characters</p>
  <?php }else { ?>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_master_details['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['item_code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['length']; ?> Characters</p>
  <?php
  mysqli_free_result($master_details);
  ?>
  <?php } ?>
<!-- end .container2 --></div>
```

To explain what is happening here:

This looks at the item that was clicked on the previous page and finds the information about it.
If it has a type_id of 4 or higher, I need it to do the following:

1. Look at the "length" of the current item.
2. Select all the items from the master_list that has a type_id of 1, 2, or 3 and a matching length to the first one.
3. Choose 1 random match.
4. Output the "name, img, and item_code in the same fashion as the first one.

If the item selected originally has a type_id of less than 4, it just posts the original information. This part works. The part from the second query does not.

I have a feeling I need another $_GET[], but not exactly sure how to go about it. The recordID get was attached to the image used as a link.

Can anyone help me to query this so that I get what I am wanting?

Here is a pic of what I am trying to do to help make more sense:

[image]

This was done by manually choosing the item to match and putting them together. I want a random item to display.

Here is what the current code looks like. This is the same thing I get with MiK's answer:

[image]

Comment: can you give here schema of both table not able to get it exact problem. Inner query can solve issue. better you explain schema of table

Comment: @aviboy2006 There are two tables, but I only use one of them for these queries. The second one is more for my information. The main table is master_list. It contains the following fields: master_id, name, img, item_code, length, and type_id. The second one just has information deciphering the type_ids.

Comment: first edit you can add your second query inside if block if. As per understanding you want to run code 1 and code 2 when type_id > 3.  I got your length checking point but not understanding point to chek type id again in second query.

Comment: Have a read about JOINs

Comment: @aviboy2006, The first query is finding out if the item is a crafted item or not. type_id determines that information. Anything that is not a crafted item needs to have a crafted item put with it on the details page. I need the lengths of both items to be the same. The field "length" tells me how characters are in the string in "item_code". Both "item_code"s have to have the same number of characters.

Comment: @Strawberry, joins bring the information from 2 tables into one row. I only have 1 table that is being used.

Comment: Plainly, that's not true.

Comment: @Strawberry, can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this issue with a combination of tweaking and the answer from MiK.

Here is the final code I ended up with:

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="category"><h2><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></h2></div>
  <?php
  $crafted = "SELECT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `type_id` <= 3 AND `length` = ". $row_master_details['length']." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $crafted);
  $citem = array();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $citem[] = $row;
      }
  }
  if ($row_master_details['type_id'] > 3) {?>
    <p><strong>Code 1</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $citem[0]['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $citem[0]['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $citem[0]['item_code']; ?></p>
    <br><br>
    <p><strong>Code 2</strong></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_master_details['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['item_code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['length']; ?> Characters</p>
  <?php }else { ?>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['name']; ?></p>
    <p><img src="img/<?php echo $row_master_details['img']; ?>" /></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['item_code']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_master_details['length']; ?> Characters</p>
  <?php
  mysqli_free_result($master_details);
  ?>
  <?php } ?>

  <p><h4>(Need a different crafted item? Refresh the page!)</h4></p>
<!-- end .container2 --></div>
```

The answer provided by MiK fixed the query, but the results were not showing because I had an array inside the array and had to call the inner array. Also, I had to fix the array name so it wasn't the same as the query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$crafted = "SELECT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `type_id` <= 3
AND `length` = $row_master_details.length ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

try

```
$crafted = "SELECT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `type_id` <= 3 
AND `length` = ".$row_master_details['length']." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Your query fails to find a matching thing since it will match against the string "Arraylength" instead of the actual value.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it still doesn't fix the issue. I will add a picture in the main post showing what it comes up looking like.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select
ml1.master_id, ml1.`name`,ml1.item_code,ml1.img,ml1.length,ml1.type_id,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.master_id,null) as craft_master_id,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.`name`,null) as craft_name,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.item_code,null) as craft_item_code,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.img,null) as craft_img,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.length,null) as craft_length,
IF(ml1.type_id > 3,ml2.type_id,null) as craft_type_id 
from 
(select * from master_list where master_id = 4) ml1
JOIN 
(select * from master_list) ml2
ON ml1.length = ml2.length
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

This query will give exactly what you need. Not required two query to run.

no need to add if else. use only on block. in code.Where you have to add crafted it just add if(craft_master_id) then only display that block else dont show.

Comment: I tried this one where you said. After adding the " " around it, I didn't have any syntax errors. I also had to change the 4 to $recordID. But when I ran it, all that was showing on the page other than header and footer was the name of the item that was called for in the Div above your code.