# How can I make this query not look for partials in length?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently this is my query:

```
$query_master = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `plain_name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `img` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `item_code` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `length` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' ORDER BY `order_number`";
```

However, when I use this it is pulling items that have a partial match even in length. How can I make the length part be an exact match?

I have tried changing it to:

```
$query_master = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `plain_name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `img` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `item_code` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `length` == '%" . $searchterm . "%' ORDER BY `order_number`";
```

in several different ways and it breaks the page.

Comment: Do not use a partial match operator on the length field?

Comment: what did you mean by length in question ? Is that length in query or length of result string?

Comment: @LakmalBodhinayaka, length is a column in the database that the query is searching. I need that one to be exact, but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, can you please give me an example of what I could use instead? I have tried several similar to the one I added when I edited my question and they break my page.

Comment: Look. [This is your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58162302/285587) where you are using the exact match operator all the way round. Why you are asking me a question you definitely know  an answer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove (%) operator for length field,

```
$query_master = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `master_list` WHERE `plain_name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `name` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `img` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `item_code` LIKE '%" . $searchterm . "%' OR `length` LIKE '" . $searchterm . "' ORDER BY `order_number`";
```

Think It will help you.

Comment: Ty, this actually worked but I also took out the ` marks around the last one as well. So ended up with

LIKE " . $searchterm . " for that part and it works. I think before I was removing too much or the wrong marks.